# Intel NUC NUC5i7RYH Ubuntu 16.04 diplay port fail

Tags: 16.04, intel, displayport

I was running the Ubuntu 14.04 on my intel Nuc NUC5i7RYH without issue. I updated to 16.04 yesterday and the display port output is no longer available. 
Not available in the display settings either. 
Any help is appreciated.

Thank you very much
Jeff

Screenshot:

[image]